# How to instantiate CDI bean at runtime via [weld] API in JavaEE [7]?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, glassfish, cdi

I am newbie in CDI and I want to instantiate CDI bean via my XML files, but not via beans.xml. Is it possible and is it normal? Or maybe I misunderstand CDI concepts?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

> A producer method is a method that acts as a source of bean instances.
>   The method declaration itself describes the bean and the container
>   invokes the method to obtain an instance of the bean when no instance
>   exists in the specified context. A producer method lets the
>   application take full control of the bean instantiation process.